# What determines when Take the Halls techs are unlocked?

Tags: king-arthurs-gold

This tech tree is shown when selecting the top left corner of the action menu on a captured Hall.

The yellow arrows showing the future path of tech tree unlocks will adjust based on votes placed.

My question is what causes these incremental unlocks to occur? Is it purely time-based or does somebody have to buy a scroll to unlock something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's purely time based and you can use what's researched till the end of the game.